# Add capability to "Editor" role to be able to view all users attachments

Tags: capabilities

I need to give access to "Editor" role, to be able to read and edit all users' media attachments. I found that a plugin can do this: https://wpfront.com/user-role-editor-pro/media-attachment-file-permissions/ .

Any ideas how to achieve this without using a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no standard capabilities just for attachments. You'd need `edit_posts`.

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Comment: By defaults, editor role already has capability to "edit_others_posts". I need the editors to be able to add feature image from images/media library (that already uploaded by admin and/or other users) when they edit other user's post.

Comment: Aren't they allowed that by default too? I think edit_others_posts takes care of that. You could try the upload files capability too, but I think that's a default for editors as well.

Comment: Yes, the upload files capability is enabled by defaults for editors role. And yet the media/images files shown in the library are only the ones that uploaded by themself.